# Intellij settings : put the end of the script tag on a new line

Tags: intellij-idea

In a vue.js file I import some dependances in script tag:

```
<script setup>
import { something } from 'dependancy';
</script>
```

When I reformat the file the end of the script tag always placed on the same line as the last import:

```
<script setup>
import { something } from 'dependancy';</script>
```

It was not the case before, I must have change some settings but I can't find which.
I tried to changed multiple settings in CodeStyle -> HTML / Javascript / Vue template. But the end of the script tag always placed on the same line as the last import when I reformat the file.

Does anyone know what setting to change?

Thank you

Comment: Please share your code style preferences (`<IDE config dir>/codestyles/<scheme name>.xml` if you are using IDE-level scheme, or `.idea\codeStyles\Project.xml` when using a project scheme)in a new support ticket so that we can investigate the issue.